# Mono Framework arm64 support?

Tags: linux, mono, debian, monodevelop, raspberry-pi4

Fellow Mono-users,
yesterday i've setup a raspberry pi 4 with the 64bit debian buster os.
I tried installing Mono as normal with `sudo apt install mono-devel`
but it failed with an error pointing to dependencies that couldn't be installed.
Than i tried the standard dependency error problem solver    `sudo apt-get update`    .
This showed me the problem:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease 
Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:6 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-raspbianstretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-raspbianstretch InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
```

If you look at the last few lines you see an error that says that arm64 architecture is not supported. So alright i'm gonna just look it up. It seems that there is some licence issue so it won't install on arm64 systems.
But when I looked it up on the official Website I see that arm64 should be supported. (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/)
Could someone please tell me, what is possible and what isn't? And if it is possible how to install it anyways.
Thank you very much in advance and have a great day!

Quantlyx

Answer (score -1):

I've already figured it out. So i'm gonna leave this online for anyone else who has the same problem.

I used these commands now and it worked perfectly fine.

https://rakhesh.com/linux-bsd/setting-up-sonarr-radarr-etc-on-my-raspberry-pi/